# Need some help troubleshooting in the new courses function written here

Tags: c++, directory, file-handling

This is a function I created for creating a course folder inside a section folder which already exists. However, when I run this function my console app just crashes. I need help trouble shooting.

The first part is simply an authentication for a correctly entered degree program. The course ID has a validation of four integers on it. I omitted that part of the code since it was error free.

In the next part I retrieve a name of sections from a file containing their name *"Sectionlist.csv"* and pass it on to strings to create directories and then create quizzes and assignments.csv files. However, this crashes the console app exactly after the message *"Course has been successfully created"*.

Here is my code for that last part. What could be the possible reasons here? Any help will be appreciated.

```cpp
string sectiondir="./data/"+program_entered+"/Sectionlist.csv";//directory of section list
string secname[3];//array for sections
ifstream sectionlist(sectiondir.c_str()); // reading section file of the degree programme
int iterator=0;

if (sectionlist.fail())
  cerr << "File couldnt be opened" << endl;
else
  while (!(sectionlist.eof())) { // reading name of sections and storing in section array
    getline(sectionlist,secname[iterator],'\n');
    iterator++;
  }

for (int i=0;i<iterator;i++) { // loop for running the section array
  string newdir="./data/"  +program_entered + "/" + secname[i] + "/" + course_entered; // directory for new course in each section
  _mkdir(newdir.c_str()); // make directory function
  string quizdir = newdir + "/quizes.csv"; // directory for resective quizes
  string assigndir = newdir + "/assignments.csv"; // directory for respective assignments
  ofstream quizes(quizdir.c_str(),ios::app); // creating a file of quizes.csv
  ofstream assignments(assigndir.c_str(),ios::app); // creating an assignment file
}
```

Comment: Can you run it in a debugger? Can you get a stack trace somehow? Can you  step through the program and check what happens? That would help a lot.

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) should take care of one bug. Whether that fixes everything is a different matter.

Comment: So i replaced !(sectionlist.eof()) with sectionlist.peek()!=EOF and it worked like a charm

Comment: Thanks.Thats saved me so much trouble while i am already very short of time on my project.

Comment: The preferred form is `while(getline(sectionlist,secname[iterator],'\n'))...`.